# Using Unirest Library with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mashape

I am trying to get this simple request to work but i get 2 errors in Xcode.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UNIRest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
    NSDictionary* headers = @{@"accept": @"application/json"};
    NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"parameter": @"value", @"foo": @"bar"};

    UNIHTTPJsonResponse *response = [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
      [request setUrl:@"http://httpbin.org/post"];
      [request setHeaders:headers];
      [request setParameters:parameters];
    }] asJson];
```

Comment: This code works: 

`NSDictionary* headers = @{@"accept": @"application/json"};
 NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"parameter": @"value", @"foo": @"bar"};

 UNIHTTPJsonResponse *response;`

Comment: Whenever I alloc init a class from the unirest library it gives me an error please help me.